# nextjs13 styles work and then suddenly stop

Tags: next.js, next.js13

i have a problem with my styles in next js. I'm using tailwind, after running npm run dev and when I first enter the server everything works fine, however immediately all the styles get deleted and i got network error like
`Request URL: http://localhost:3000/_next/static/css/app/layout.css?v=1707472278915 Request Method: GET Status Code: 404 Not Found Remote Address: [::1]:3000 Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin`

i tried reinstall app

Comment: It feels like the CORS policy on localhost is getting in the way. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/why-does-my-http-localhost-cors-origin-not-work) will help?

Comment: Can you add enough information so we would have a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).